# How to Count Empty Column for Each Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate

I have three tables:

```
Software
   software_id
   software_name

SoftwareLicenses
   software_license_id
   software_id
   type
   expiration_date

SoftwareLicenseKey
   software_license_key_id
   software_license_id
   software_license_key
   user
```

I want to select everything but also want to generate a field in SoftwareLicense that is the quantity available for each SoftwareLicense. I wanted to accomplish this by counting the SoftwareLicenseKey records with an empty user column. Can this be accomplished using Hibernate and if not what would the SQL Query look like?

```
SELECT *
   from Software software 
   left outer join SoftwareLicense softwarelicense on software.SoftwareID=softwarelicense.SoftwareID 
   left outer join SoftwareLicenseKey softwarelicensekey on softwarelicense.SoftwareLicenseID=softwarelicensekey.SoftwareLicenseID
```

Brings back all the data but I don't know how to count the empty columns and add that as a column in the software license?

Comment: Show us what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: You can use Count(*) to count all the Empty Columns.Can u provide your Table Data Detials -- @shakka

Answer (score 0):

Sure, assuming you have `Set<SoftwareLicense> softwareLicenses` mapped in `Software` and `Set<SoftwareLicenseKey> keys` in `SoftwareLicense` you can use a JPQL/HQL query similar to the following

```
SELECT s.id, COUNT(CASE WHEN k.user IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
FROM Software s
LEFT JOIN s.softwareLicenses l
LEFT JOIN l.keys k
GROUP BY s.id
```